# Is there any point in batch inserting rows with MySQL when using transactions?

Tags: java, mysql

Specifically, I'm using MySQL v5.5.41 and performing the inserts using Java JDBC (the driver is mysql-connector-java-5.1.30), although I don't know if the driver I'm using relevant.

I'm running a once-off application to insert a reasonably large number of rows across 7 tables. Each of my "entries" (rows relating to the same data) consists of a variable number of rows across 6 of the tables, and a single row in the other table that relates to the others (approx. 10-20 rows to be inserted across all 7 tables per "entry", but occasionally there might be significantly more).

I'm wrapping each "entry" insert inside a transaction that is committed after all the rows for the entry have been inserted.

My question is whether or not it is necessary to batch the row inserts into each of my tables that would usually require multiple row inserts e.g. using `addBatch()` and `batchExecute()` in Java?

For example, if I was to call the `executeUpdate()` function for every row insert in a table (no batching), does the JDBC library I'm using optimize and ultimately only issue a single multi-valued insert when I commit the transaction later? Or, if there is optimization in these circumstances, maybe it's carried out by MySQL itself?

Comment: You can use `VALUES()` to insert multiple rows at the same time in SQL.  I would recommend this, because it reduces the overhead of communicating to the database.

Comment: I know, but my question is whether or not it's even necessary for me to do that, since the inserts will be wrapped in a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will still be multiple statements - and thus multiple in flight requests. Using transactions does *not* affect how statements are executed (or batched for such execution).

Transactions occur entirely within the MySQL engine itself. Using a transactions is a *good* step and it does greatly help with performance mainly because 'commits' (and associated data flushes/syncs) are themselves reduced.

For a *low latency* connection the performance will be equivalent. However batching can still play a factor in 'higher latency' connections. This is because the individual statements must *still* be round-tripped to the sever. (Eg. with a 5ms connection at most 200 statements can be executed per second.)

In any case, the 'definitive performance answer' is a benchmark under the specific load/task/configuration.

Comment: Latency is not an issue for me, my app will run on the same machine as the DB. Just to be clear, are you saying that when I commit a transaction, if I issued multiple separate insert commands (for rows in the same table) then MySQL will still execute those multiple inserts separately. So, there will not be any optimization unless I use a batch insert before committing the transaction?

Comment: @RTF The same statements are send by the driver irregardless of any transaction in effect. However since the individual DML statements are within a transaction then performance will still be "much better" than N individual transactions. Run a benchmark to compare how individual (in a transaction) vs. batched (one DML statement) inserts compare.

Answer (score 2):

Batching is very important, regardless of transactions.

In many tests, I have seen about 10x (not 10%) speed up when doing a single `INSERT` with 100 rows instead of 100 1-row `INSERTs`.  (For "same machine", latency is low, but not zero.)

Think of all the overhead of a statement -- network latency, process swapping, parsing, and many mutexes.